# Програмная точка доступа на Broadcom4313

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

Подскажите, как настроить программную точку доступа Wi-fi на адаптере Broadcom 4313. Какие при этом использовать драйвера. ОС Ubunta 11.10.

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса; для настройки роутера заходим на 192.168.0.1 или 192.168.1.1 (admin/admin) по дефолту, на убунте в network manager'e выбираете беспроводную сеть, там вписываете мак и пароль, если задали его в настройках роутера. На крайней случай ставите программу wicd, и работатет с ней.

Answer (score 1):

Hostapd. Разве бывают программные?

Comment: программную точку доступа можно создать имея встроенный Wifi адаптер, в моем случае не включается режим Master. имея единственные рабочие драйвера b43-fwcutter

Comment: Некоторые могут работать некоторые не могут! Танцы с бубном неизбежны. У меня чип 4318 так и не получилось

Comment: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/6880030

Comment: Вот этого я и ожидал. Ждем-с. спасибо за ссылку